# How to repeat nth line of a file by m times

Tags: awk, sed

I want to repeat an nth line in a text file by m times but I could not able to do it.
My file is

```
#
1:host
1:host
#
```

I want to repeat `"1:host"` in such a way that I get total 12 lines of `"1:host"`.

So the expected result should be:

```
#
1:host
1:host
1:host
1:host
1:host
1:host
1:host
1:host
1:host
1:host
1:host
1:host
```

Comment: Please write an example of your input file, and the output file you want.

Comment: sed doesn't handle *numbers* well, but here's a horrible kludge that will work for your particular values of M and N: `sed '2{N;p;p;p;p;p;}' filename`

Comment: ...Or, to make it shorter and more cryptic, `sed '2{N;h;G;G;p;}' filename`

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: This might help you on your way: `awk '($0~str){c--;f=1}($0!~str)&&c&&f { while(c-->0) print str }1' c=12 str="1:host" file`

Comment: Dear Kvantour, I will take case in future posts. Your suggestion worked for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this all you're trying to do?

```
$ cat file
#
1:host
1:host
foo

$ awk 'NR==3{for (i=1; i<=10; i++) print} 1' file
#
1:host
1:host
1:host
1:host
1:host
1:host
1:host
1:host
1:host
1:host
1:host
1:host
foo
```

Comment: Perfect answer Mr. Ed Morton.